# Stacking windows without a window manager

Tags: window

(Ubuntu 22.04.)

I suppose the following is somewhat trivial with a window manager, but I couldn't get used to window managers yet.

This is what I often need in my current workflow: I have a code editor occupying half of the screen (or so), and Google Chrome snapped-occupying the other half. I also need Chrome Dev Tools open; but I need it stacked on the top of Google Chrome exactly. And I prefer to be able to switch between Dev-tools and Google Chrome from the keyboard.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [I3](https://i3wm.org/) which is a tiling window manager and highly configurable.

Tiling, moving within the screen(s) are accomplished via keyboard hooks.

Installing of I3 on Ubuntu is described [here](https://kifarunix.com/install-i3-windows-manager-on-ubuntu/)

Some Arch linux derivative (ArchBang or ArcoLinux) have I3 as an install option.